# ALL @FXML Attributes are NULL in my controller (SPRING BOOT - JAVA-FX Integration)

Tags: java, spring, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a software for member management, I'm using spring boot, spring data integrated with JAVA-FX.
It was all fine until I created a view which has a table with all the adherent members associated to a main member. When I open the view, it loads perfectly, but in the method I use for loading the data of the adherent members it throws an exception.

This is my code:

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="522.0" prefWidth="834.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.controller.VistaAdherenteSocioController">
    <top>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="859.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="lblTitulo" text="Socios adherentes de: ">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="784.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <ScrollPane prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="784.0">
                    <content>
                        <TableView fx:id="tblSociosAdh" prefHeight="239.0" prefWidth="782.0">
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colNombre" editable="false" prefWidth="231.0"    text="Nombre Completo" />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colTipoDoc" editable="false" prefWidth="106.0" text="Tipo Doc." />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colNroDoc" editable="false" prefWidth="145.0" text="Nro. Documento" />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colFechaNac" editable="false" minWidth="8.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Fecha de Nac." />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colVinculo" prefWidth="87.0" text="Vinculo" />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="colDeBaja" prefWidth="75.0" text="Baja" />
                            </columns>
                        </TableView>
                    </content>
                </ScrollPane>
            </children>
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
            </BorderPane.margin>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="181.0" prefWidth="834.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="lblSocioSelec" text="Socio adherente seleccionado:">
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="25.0" top="15.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="834.0">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnBaja" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Baja">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnEditar" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Editar">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnDetalles" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Detalles">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="844.0">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnNuevo" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="235.0" text="Nuevo">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets top="10.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnVolver" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="233.0" text="Volver">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
package com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.controller;

import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.model.SocioAdherente;
import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.model.SocioTitular;
import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.service.ISocioAdherenteService;
import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.service.ISocioTitularService;
import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.ui.SocioAdherenteWrapper;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class VistaAdherenteSocioController implements Initializable {

    private SocioTitular socio;

    private HashMap<Long, SocioAdherente> socios;

    private SocioAdherente socioSeleccionado;

    //autowired inyection of service classes here
    
    @FXML
    private Label lblTitulo;

    @FXML
    private TableView<SocioAdherenteWrapper> tblSociosAdh;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SocioAdherenteWrapper, String> colNombre;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SocioAdherenteWrapper, String> colTipoDoc;

    //other FXML atributes

   

    @Transactional
    public void initData(SocioTitular socioTit) {
        this.socio = sociotitser.findById(socioTit.getNroSocio());
        //Decirle a hibernate que traiga la coleccion
        Hibernate.initialize(socio.getSociosAdherentes());
        //setear titulo
        if (lblTitulo != null) {
            lblTitulo.setText("Socios adherentes de: " + socio.getNroDocumento() + " - " + socio.getNombreCompleto());
            // Resto del código...
        } else {
            System.err.println("lblTitulo es nulo en initData.");
        }
        //obtener socios adherentes del socio en cuestion
        List<SocioAdherente> sociosAdherentes = socio.getSociosAdherentes();
        // Convertir a wrappers
        List<SocioAdherenteWrapper> wrappers = sociosAdherentes.stream()
                .map(SocioAdherenteWrapper::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //convertir a hashmap
        this.socios = (HashMap<Long, SocioAdherente>) sociosAdherentes.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(SocioAdherente::getNroSocio, socio -> socio));

        //Mapeo de columnas :)
        colNombre.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nombreCompletoProperty());
        colTipoDoc.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().tipoDocProperty());
        colNroDoc.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().nroDocumentoProperty());
        colVinculo.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().vinculoProperty());
        colDeBaja.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().bajaProperty());

        //Setear items
        tblSociosAdh.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(wrappers));

        //other listeners for tables, buttons, etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //btn y label de acciones disabled por defecto
        /*lblSocioSelec.setDisable(true);
        btnBaja.setDisable(true);
        btnEditar.setDisable(true);
        btnDetalles.setDisable(true);*/
    }

}
```

INDEX:
(this is where I load the different views depending on what the user select, like a side navbar)

```
package com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.controller;

import com.ebernet.bomberos_socios.model.SocioTitular;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class IndexController implements Initializable {`

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @FXML
    private Pane mainContent;

    //another methods for opening other views

     //this one here works perfectly, and has the same logic behind that the 
      one im having problems.
    public void editarSocio(SocioTitular socioToEdit) {
        //se carga la vista
        loadView("/fxml/editarSocio.fxml");
        //se obtiene el objeto EditarSocioController gracias a el application context (Gracias SPRING!!!)
        EditarSocioController controller = context.getBean(EditarSocioController.class);
        //se le setea al controlador el objeto socio el cual tiene que editar
        controller.setSocioEditar(socioToEdit);
    }

     //this is the one that doesn't work
    public void vistaSociosAdherentes(SocioTitular socio) {        
        //se carga la vista y el controller!
        loadView("/fxml/vistaAdherenteSocio.fxml");    
        //se obtiene el objeto DetalleSocioController gracias a el application context (Gracias SPRING!!!)        
        VistaAdherenteSocioController controller = context.getBean(VistaAdherenteSocioController.class);
        //se le setea al controlador el objeto socio el cual se quiere ver detalle
        if (controller != null) {
            System.out.println("CONTROLLER: "+controller);
            // Imprime todas las instancias gestionadas por Spring de VistaAdherenteSocioController
            String[] beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(VistaAdherenteSocioController.class);
            System.out.println("Instancias gestionadas por Spring de VistaAdherenteSocioController: " + Arrays.toString(beanNames));
            controller.initData(socio);
            
        } else {
            System.err.println("El controlador es nulo después de cargar la vista.");
        }

    }
    //general method for loading the view
    private void loadView(String view) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(view));   
            loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
            Pane newLoadedPane = loader.load();        

            mainContent.getChildren().clear();
            mainContent.getChildren().add(newLoadedPane);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

And at LAST, the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.colNombre" is null

It works like this:
I have a side navbar that acts like a menu, the user selects one of the options, and it's the index controller who is responsible for loading the view in the center pane. Also, when it is required, other views (actually, the controllers of that views) can call one of the methods of indexcontroller (I use autowired for injecting the instance in other controllers) in order to load the view that the user needs.

I tested a lot of things, but none worked.

I have 5 other views with their respective controller that work perfectly!
I dont know why this doesn't.

Thank you for reading this and try to help me solve my problem, it has really frustrated me. this is one of my first developments and the first one with java fx integration with spring boot.

Also apologize for my rusty English!

I tried deleting both the controller and the FXML view, to load the view without spring boot, checked multiple times that the fx:id and the names of the @FXML attributes match.

just in case, here is my @SpringBootApplication and my @Application class, also a StageListener.

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application{
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception{
        //here we do any kind of work that DO NOT runs on the user interface
        //to prepare the aplication, to begin, to load
        ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> initializer = 
            ac->{
               ac.registerBean(Application.class, ()->JavaFXApplication.this);
               ac.registerBean(Parameters.class, this::getParameters);
               ac.registerBean(HostServices.class, this::getHostServices);
            };
        this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .sources(BomberosSociosApplication.class)
                .initializers(initializer)
                .run(getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.context.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(primaryStage));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception{
        this.context.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}

class StageReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent{
    
    public Stage getStage() {
        return Stage.class.cast(getSource());
    }

    public StageReadyEvent(Stage source) {
        super(source);
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class BomberosSociosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(JavaFXApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
public class StageListener implements ApplicationListener<StageReadyEvent>{

    private final String appTitle;
    private final Resource fxml;
    private final ApplicationContext ac;

    StageListener(@Value("${spring.application.ui.title}")String appTitle,
                  @Value("${classpath:/fxml/index.fxml}") Resource resource, ApplicationContext ac) {
        this.appTitle = appTitle;
        this.fxml = resource;
        this.ac = ac;
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StageReadyEvent event) {
        try {
            Stage stage = event.getStage();
            URL url = this.fxml.getURL();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(ac::getBean);
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle(appTitle);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StageListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Also, here are my classes SocioTitular, and SocioAdherente:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name="socio_titular")
public class SocioTitular {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="nro_socio")
    private Long nroSocio;
    @Column(name="nombre_completo")
    private String nombreCompleto;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_documento")
    private TipoDocumento tipoDoc;
    @Column(name="nro_documento")
    private Long nroDocumento;
    @Column(name="fecha_nacimiento")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    @Column(name="fecha_ingreso")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaIngreso;
    @Column(name="fecha_baja")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaBaja;
    private boolean baja;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_baja")
    private TipoBaja tipoBaja;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_domicilio")
    private Domicilio domicilio;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cobrador")
    private Cobrador cobrador;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "socioDeudor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Deuda> deudas;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "socioTitular", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SocioAdherente>sociosAdherentes;
    
}
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name="socio_adherente")
public class SocioAdherente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="nro_socio_adherente")
    private Long nroSocio;
    @Column(name="nombre_completo")
    private String nombreCompleto;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_documento")
    private TipoDocumento tipoDoc;
    @Column(name="nro_documento")
    private Long nroDocumento;
    @Column(name="fecha_nacimiento")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    @Column(name="fecha_baja")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaBaja;
    private boolean baja;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_baja")
    private TipoBaja tipoBaja;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_socio_titular")
    private SocioTitular socioTitular;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_vinculo")
    private Vinculo vinculo;
}
```

Comment: [FXML controllers should be prototype scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802384/creating-new-instance-of-component-each-time-fxmlloader-calls-applicationcontex/77802518#77802518).  You may have other issues with your code. For reference: an example of [integrating FXML and SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service).

Comment: yes, i have an integration similar to the one in that post.. y got it from a youtube video from a chanel called "SpringDeveloper"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPy9mc_O_gU&t=582s
And it actually works, it has separated classes, one for spring boot aplication, and the other for JAVA FX..
I will try the scope thing you mentioned, that makes sense, maybe spring re-uses an instance of the controller and thats why the atributes are null.
But the weird thing is that the other views and controllers work perfectly fine!

Comment: To get debugging assistance, you need to provide a [mcve] (please read and understand the link).

Comment: im sorry, this is my first post at stackoverflow, and i speak spanish, i know how to defend myself in english but still mi text comprehesion is not the best.
I read the article you send me, and i did what i understood! kind of cleaned the code for it to be easier to "try". tell me if i need to do something else. im looking foward to get this problem solved asap! thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: There is a [spanish version of the minimal reproducible example page](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I linked in my earlier comment.  Basically, if you copy and pasted only the code from your question and made no other other changes or additions could you reproduce your issue?

Comment: ok, thanks but im pretty sure i have the right code in the integration.. because everithing works, except this particular view. weird
The code there is now should be "testeable"

Comment: but i will read it again just in case!

Comment: I can't run your code to reproduce your issue, there is no JavaFX application or SpringBoot application to run it, nor any required class such as SocioAdherente, so the code will not compile.

Comment: ok, i get it now, i thought there was some kindo of character limit, thats why i didnt add everithing, im sorry and im really thankfull for your time.
I think now you have all you need to run it, there are some attributes from the model classes that i didnt include but you can replace their  data type for strings or smth

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, it was the @Transactional annotation. I dont know why, but that was somehow causing all my @FXML attributes to be null.
I realized because i re-did everithing from scratch,  both the view and the controller... and for every new component i added, i tested that it worked.

Comment: The reason why may be because [Transactional beans create proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background), and potentially the proxy doesn't have the FXML injected fields available.  (just speculation on my part).

Comment: In any case, it is worth considering [where does @Transactional belong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/where-does-the-transactional-annotation-belong).  IMO, if using Spring, it is probably better to extract service logic and transaction semantics from the FXML UI controllers and instead place them in `@Service` annotated transactional services.